# Automated deployment for application, webhooks or git-pull/restart

Tags: git, github, deployment

I would like to hear you opinions about automated deployment from Github.

The first solution is to write a cron script that will pull every minute and reinstall the application if changes was made.

The second is to use Github webhooks to signal the server to pull and reinstall.

The second solution seems like the better solution, but will also take more time to setup. Is there any critical cons regarding the pull approach.

In generel, what do you see as the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

Either of them should work fine for automating the deployment process.

Your first option: Write a cron job that will pull timely and reinstall accordingly

> In this case you have to configure the post-receive hook in order to
>   automate. If you want any custom requirements that you would like to
>   do along. Please use the first option even if it has work involved.

Your second option: Use Github webhooks

> In this case you have to configure the service "GITHub
>   Auto-Deployment" in order to achieve this. This is relatively easy
>   compared to the first option but if you want any other requirement
>   that is not in the service, then you will have to go to option 1.